# Get country code from numbers that are different length

Tags: android

We know that there are numbers with different length. In Europe we mostly have 9 digits numbers plus country code.

In North America we often find 10 digits numbers.

I am trying to get my head around an idea how to get a country code from a number that may be of different length.

Any ideas? Maybe you know some working libs that can do it?

Comment: there are fewer than 10 possible lengths for a phone number and around 200 countries. You can't map from the first to the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key facts:

1. The country code is always at the start of the number, so it is easy to find no matter the length of the number.
2. There is no overlap, as @Luis points out.

A (looks pretty) complete list of country codes is give [here](http://countrycode.org/). If you sort them by length (shortest first) and run through the list comparing the first `n` digits with the list entries you will get the answer.

However, if you look at the list you wall see that there are various groups of codes. A more intelligent approach would note that:

- All numbers beginning with 1 are US, Canada or other US related places in which case the next three digits tell you which.
- 7 is Khazakstan
- Apart from 20, all country codes beginning with 2 are three digits.
- and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about phone number country codes. Country codes are defined by the ITU ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes ). The country codes can be 1, 2 or 3 digits. Your only alternative is to have a list of all country codes and parse it from there. Note that there is no overlap; for instance, +44 belongs to the UK, and no country starts with just 4.

**UPDATE**: The North American Area has 4 digit prefixes, not 1, composed of +1 and a NPA of 3 digit (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan). The same rule applies though, in that +1-NPA cannot be repeated. Barbados seems to be +1246, but no other country or region can start with +1246. You can get the list of all NPA from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_North_American_Numbering_Plan_area_codes

Comment: Thanks to you I have a clue now. There is one but. +1 is to the united states and this digit '1' may be the first one in Barbados  BB / BRB   1 246

Comment: No, barbados is just 246. To dial from USA, you would dial 011 246; from UK, 00 246, but from nowhere 1 246

Comment: Actually, the dialing code for Barbados is +1246 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan ), not +246. If you call from the the UK you dial 00 1246 according to what I see in wikipedia. Within the US you don't need 011 because you don't need to get out of the North American area. I edit my response to clarify this

Answer (score 1):

Country codes are parsed left-to-right with deterministic endpoints similar to the idea of Huffman coding. ie, if you see a 1 first, stop, it's the US/Canada/related territories. If you see most other numbers besides 7 (Russia/Kazakhstan), keep going. Some of those numbers may terminate on the second value.

The list of country codes is here: http://www.howtocallabroad.com/codes.html

It should be trivial for you to take this and write your own string parser of a phone number in order to determine which country code is present.

(don't forget that if these are numbers from within a particular country, you also have to take that country's exit code into account, which is also on the page I linked)

Edit: Oh, I guess luis covered it. But Jakob is incorrect in his comment about Barbados. Barbados is the same country code as the US; the 246 is its local "area code" within the US/Canada's country code.